# Evaluation of method in Watch window cannot be called in this context

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to see the `DateTimeOffset` values of some objects in a collection in the Watch window. So I typed:

```
collection.Select(v => v.CreatedAt.ToString("O"))
```

Trying to evaluate this however yields an error:

> Evaluation of method System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].get_Items requires calling method System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.get_ID, which cannot be called in this context.

I could have just specified `v.CreatedAt` which works but I'm interested in the milliseconds too, so I'm using the `O` format. Just calling `ToString()` yields the same error.

So I'm wondering what is "this context" in the error message, and is there a chance to extend this context to make this possible?

Comment: did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: Just to add some info to this one, I've encountered the same error in a conditional breakpoint for calling a method of my own which calls `Enum.GetValues` under `System` but interestingly it says it requires calling `System.RuntimeType.GetEnumValues`.  It's running under .NET 4.6.1.

Comment: I've had this issue too with the evaluation of a DebuggerDisplay expression... one particularly strange thing is that the problem is intermittent, but can still occur even when I remove date formatting from the debugger display string.

Answer (score 0):

> So I'm wondering what is "this context" in the error message, and is
> there a chance to extend this context to make this possible?

It seems that culture should be specified, try:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
collection.Select(v => string.Format(culture,"{0:D}",v.CreatedAt));
```

Also for `IQueryable` type of `collection` only limited number of functions can be called inside of projections, so call `ToList()` before:

```
collection.ToList().Select(v => string.Format(culture, "{0:D}",v.CreatedAt));
```

Comment: Does your reply also refer to the Watch window in Visual Studio?